# SQL - Remove tuples from a select based on occurences on a specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Consider the simple table representing the history of a race:

```
 laphistory(race_id integer,lap_number integer,pos_number integer,
 driver_label text,id integer NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id) ...)
```

Now, consider the following example:

```
race_id;lap_number;pos_number;driver_label;id
1      ;1         ;1         ;"Matheus"   ;1
1      ;1         ;2         ;"Nicolas"   ;2
1      ;1         ;3         ;"Diego"     ;3
1      ;2         ;1         ;"Nicolas"   ;4
1      ;2         ;2         ;"Diego"     ;5
1      ;2         ;3         ;"Matheus"   ;6
1      ;3         ;1         ;"Nicolas"   ;7
1      ;3         ;2         ;"Diego"     ;8
1      ;4         ;1         ;"Diego"     ;9
```

According to the instance above, the result of race 1 (ordering the position of the last lap for each driver) should be (we can ignore here the "pos_number"):

```
race_id;lap_number;pos_number;driver_label;id
1      ;4         ;1         ;"Diego"     ;9
1      ;3         ;1         ;"Nicolas"   ;7
1      ;2         ;3         ;"Matheus"   ;6
```

Querying the BD using the simple query:

```
select * from laphistory order by lap_number DESC, pos_number ASC
```

Will bring the following result:

```
race_id;lap_number;pos_number;driver_label;id
1      ;4         ;1         ;"Diego"     ;9  <<<
1      ;3         ;1         ;"Nicolas"   ;7  <<<
1      ;3         ;2         ;"Diego"     ;8
1      ;2         ;1         ;"Nicolas"   ;4
1      ;2         ;2         ;"Diego"     ;5
1      ;2         ;3         ;"Matheus"   ;6  <<<
1      ;1         ;1         ;"Matheus"   ;1
1      ;1         ;2         ;"Nicolas"   ;2
1      ;1         ;3         ;"Diego"     ;3
```

It is correct if we consider the first occurrence of each driver.However, I don't know how to select it. Any ideas?

Comment: Your expected output is inconsistent with what you need. For example, for lap 2, driver should be 'Nicolas', not 'Matheus'

Comment: Thanks. But I think it is correct. Maybe I need to explain it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL's [`window function`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html) can be apply to get the desired output:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY driver_label ORDER BY lap_number DESC
            ) AS rank
    FROM race
    ) t
WHERE rank = 1
```

Or

[`SQL-DISTINCT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (driver_label) *
FROM race
ORDER BY driver_label ASC 
    ,lap_number DESC
```

Comment: Aewsome. Thanks. I just had to add an  "order by lap_number desc" on the first option. All good.
Option 2 does the job but can't return it  ordered by anything different then the driver_label. 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Simple GROUP BY should do what you need:

```
select race_id, lap_number, min(id) from foo
group by race_id, lap_number
order by race_id asc, lap_number desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution thanks to Vivek.S' awesome answer. Just did some adapts:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY driver_label ORDER BY lap_number DESC
            ) AS rank
    FROM laphistory  where lap_number<= $X$ 
    ) t
WHERE rank = 1 order by lap_number DESC, pos_number ASC
```

Now I can have the drivers order for a lap $x$.
Thanks!